# ajax success function is printing [object Object] instead of plain text. Why?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, playframework-2.0

jQuery code:

```
function ajaxsubmit(){
$.ajax({
    url: "/update",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html"
}).success(function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data);
  });
}
```

and my Java function:

```java
public static Result ajaxupdate() {
    String done = "very good";
    return ok("very good").as("text/plain");
}
```

the alert is giving `[object Object]`, instead of plain text `"very good"`. why?

Comment: Open it in chrome, put a breakpoint on the alert line, and mouse over `data` it will tell you exactly what the object looks like internally.

Comment: im guessing jquery is converting your json to an object literal.

Comment: have you tried  alert(data.d);

Comment: Please keep tags out of the title.  We have a tag system.  It works great.  Tags are given precedence in searching, in SEO, etc etc.  Cramming tags artificially into your title has no benefits.

Comment: Oh okay sure, i ll take it out.. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add dataType: "text" and change complete() with success()

```
function ajaxsubmit(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/update",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html"
    }).success(function(data) {
          $('#result').html(data);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Cristi, i am getting it now.! great!

Comment: Cristi, now i am appending html element as response data. how can i make it so that each ajaxsubmit function appends an html element. now it is appending only once because the id of div element becomes unique. see my edit above please.

Answer (score 4):

you want to use:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

so you JavaScript will look like:

```
function ajaxsubmit(){
$.ajax({
    url: "/update",
    type: "POST",
}).complete(function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
}
```

Your Java code looks like it is wrapping your string into an object before it sends it back to the client, JSON.stringify() will show you the structure of the object that is being returned and from there you can work out what property of the returned object contains your return variable (Probably something like data.data or data.return)

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery documentation clearly answers your question. From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
complete(jqXHR, textStatus)
<...>
two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string
```

You can find more about jqXHR in documentation.
If you want to use the response string, consider opting for .success method. You may have to explicitly provide .contentType

Comment: contentType is for what you send to the server, dataType is for what you get.

Comment: okay, many thanks friendzis, great information, learnt one more thing!